# I am not able to create script in DP using QTP11

Tags: qtp

I have installed QTP11 trail version. Using it when I try to create script in DP for ex (Browser("title:=Welcome home").Page("title:=Welcome Home"))
When I type "." after closing the brace for Browser The page element is not listed in the drop down.
But when I create script in normal mode that is Browser("Welcome home").Page("Welcome Home")
Then it is displaying. Can some one please help me if I am missing any thing while installing it.

Thanks
Vinny

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you are using DP you are bypassing the use of the Object Repository, you are either statically or dynamically defining the objects. The drop down that appears after you type Browser or Page autofills your selection using the OR. But since you are using DP, you won't get that feature. You can read more about it here http://www.qtpworld.com/index.php?cid=62

Answer (score 0):

[@Amelio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2250329) gave the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15906588/3848) but I would like to expand about it a bit.

QTP tests are based on VBScript which is a dynamic language, this means that you can't in general know if something will work until you try to actually execute it. When you write `Browser("title:=.*").Foo` then at runtime the script engine will try to see if the object returned by `Browser("title:=.*")` *knows how to* `Foo`.

In order to make developing tests easier QTP's IDE performs auto suggestions while typing but just because something doesn't show up in the suggestion list doesn't mean it wont work when run (case in point try `Browser("title:=.*").Highlight`).

The suggestion list QTP presents is the union of

- the methods and properties the object supports (both statically and via [`RegisterUserFunc`](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/12/understanding-registeruserfunc-syntax-with-example/))
- For objects in the object repository => child objects of the specified object

The second bullet means that for `Page` in some cases you may have `Link` children and in some not, it depends on what objects you have in the repository. In DP there are **no** child objects so QTP only suggests methods and properties that belong to the typed object.